# Lagom Persistence | Cassandra | thenPersistAll throwing batch too large

Tags: cassandra, persistence, lagom

I am using the Lagom persistence and while trying to persist the events in Cassandra, I am using thenPersistAll but on running the service on the DC/OS cluster, there occasionally is an `InvalidQueryException - Batch too large` exception thrown.

What might be the issue and how can it be resolved? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How many events are you attempting to persist at once, and what is the size of those events? Cassandras batch  limit I believe is measured in kb, and I think defaults to 50kb. If your events are much bigger than that, then you should consider whether you're using events correctly, generally events should be small, eg no more than a few kb when serialized to json.

Comment: Thanks for the input @James.Tried figuring out the size of a single event in order to debug as suggested. However, noticed that while printing the event in order to get its size just before the "thenPeristAll" method, the event is still not serialized to JSON. So we believe either Lagom is serializing it internally. Anyways we are using the default configurations that is a batch size of 200 during batch persist and a memory size of 50KB at Cassandra size for max size of batch. If our assumption is correct, can you please guide us with how we can calculate the size of the Json being persisted.

Comment: We are able to churn out the numbers:
1.) Size of compressed event persisted to Cassandra: ~1.3KB
2.) Size of complete Cassandra record: ~1.8KB
3.) The maximum number of events in a batch which is causing the issue is 180.
4.) Maximum batch size configured in Cassandra: 50KB

Please suggest do these numbers make a correct set. If not then what do you suggest?